# Please rate limit the password reset functionality

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, email, rate-limiting, account-recovery

Just received ~70 unsolicited password reset mails from Super User, so abusive...

Comment: There are other ways to troll your email if one knows your address, but agree that rate limiting it on SE's side makes sense.

Comment: You're not finishing your sentence

Comment: "and yet so warm". Is that the closer?

Comment: @random ... and [I still have no closer](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=i+still+have+no+closer).

Comment: Yeahhhhh sorry about that. We'll put some rate-limiting in place there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sorry for the inconvenience this has caused you. Can't believe we never had any throttling here... I'm pretty sure everyone just assumed that *of course* we did. :)

We put throttles in place about a month ago, both at the IP and the account level, so this sort of abuse should no longer be possible.

Comment: Figured out it was a troll that wanders around the sites, not a targeted attempt; it can be a bit scary at first, but glad nothing really happened. Yeah, throttling for the win! No more mail bombs in the future... :-)